# Natural join mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, join, natural-join

I would like to see how many medals a country have won. So I decide to combine the tables www_result and www_country. They have the attribute country_id in common. This is my code so far but I get syntax errors, and I can't seem to find the reason.

```
SELECT * FROM www_results WHERE position = 1 OR position = 2 OR position = 3
NATURAL JOIN 
www_countries;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what are the errors you are getting ? Post those

Comment: Maybe the order of the arguments is wrong. Altough I've never used a natural join, might I suggest you try `SELECT * FROM www_results NATURAL JOIN www_countries WHERE position <= 3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have things in the wrong order, do the JOINs then apply the WHERE clause...

You should also specify which table you are referring to when referencing a field name.  It's not always necessary but makes it more readable and less prone to bugs.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    www_results
NATURAL JOIN 
    www_countries
WHERE
    www_results.position IN (1, 2, 3)
;
```

I also actually recommend against `NATURAL JOIN` any way.  If you incidentally have fields with the same name, you get unwanted behaviour.  I would use explicit `INNER JOIN`s.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    www_results
INNER JOIN 
    www_countries
        ON  www_results.country_id = www_countries.country_id
        --  Replace the "country_id" with whatever field you want to join on
WHERE
    www_results.position IN (1, 2, 3)
;
```